# Moderator tools privileges page on Beta sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, beta-sites, privileges-page

See the "Access To Moderator Tools" page on a beta site ([example](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)), where it references delete votes:

> ### How many times can I vote to delete per day?
>
> At 10k, you can cast 5 delete votes per day. An additional vote is
>   granted per 1000 reputation, to a maximum of 30 delete votes per day
>   at 35k reputation.

Because moderator tools access on beta sites only needs 2000 reputation, this should be reworded. If there are no delete votes until 10k, it should be explicitly stated, but if you have 5 delete votes at 2000 reputation, then this might be misleading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've updated that page to use a variable rather than a hard-coded "10k" in that sentence. It should display correctly in every site's help center based on the correct rep thresholds for that site.